# Can Yesterday be used for Tomorrow?

Tags: grammar, expressions

In a recent episode of [TV series Suits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5895096/?ref_=ttep_ep4) (which revolves around Lawyers) character Mike says the line:

> You heard Cahill. He needs an answer yesterday.

Isn't [it](https://www.google.com/#q=%22You+heard+Cahill.+He+needs+an+answer+yesterday.%22) incorrect English? Can *yesterday* be used for *tomorrow*? If so what are the rules?

I heard a similar use of yesterday in the same TV series in a very old episode but took that to be my weaker understanding of English grammar then.

Comment: In case brando’s answer didn't flesh it out clearly enough: no, _yesterday_ cannot be used to mean _tomorrow_. In the context you quote here, the meaning is exaggerated and hyperbolic, but literal: it means ‘the day _before_ today’.

Comment: As the old management joke goes: Manager screaming into a phone: "Of course I want it yesterday! If it wanted it today, I'd have asked you tomorrow!".

Comment: I understand what this quote means, but should it not be in the past tense: "He **needed** an answer yesterday?"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means he needs it extremely urgently. It means he wants an answer right away, and he would have preferred to have it before now (yesterday).

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/need_yesterday):

> *Verb*
>   **need it yesterday**
>
> (*idiomatic*) To need something immediately or urgently; to **need
>   something that is *already late***.
>
> 1972 Hearings, reports and prints of the Senate Committee on
>   Government Operations, U.S. G.P.O., p119 We need help - and we need it
>   yesterday - if local government is to remain a viable entity in our
>   society [...]
>
> 1980 Thomas A. Rullo, Advances in computer programming management,
>   Heyden, p153 Many people in systems work are so used to digging in and
>   getting the job done in record time (we need it yesterday!) that the
>   thought of taking several weeks to develop a plan before "doing"
>   anything might sound like heresy to them.
>
> 2006 Climate change: the "citizen's agenda", eighth report of session
>   2006-07, Vol. 2: Oral and written evidence, Volume 2, The Stationery
>   Office, p511 We need a cultural change and shift in people’s
>   perceptions of the concept of “progress” but we need it yesterday and
>   are fast running out of time.
>
> 2006 Joyce Rosenwald & Michel Bonner, The Sinclair Solution, p154
>   “Take care of it then,” the President shouted. “I need a summary of
>   the situation and I need a solution. And, I need it yesterday.”

Comment: You should add the appropriate reference(s). I've added one for you.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that there is a term for this, [hyperbole](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyperbole).